# How to use a predfined separate prune set in Weka (alternatives in R or Python also acceptable)

Tags: python, r, decision-trees, weka

I recently ran into a problem that seems to have considerate local effects, in space and time in fact: Two objects that are close are likely yo be in a similar state (if they are in the same year). I'm interested in modelling the behavior over time, but many classifiers find rules that are based on locality.

Now I have taken some action to prevent that of course, such as downsampling the set to achieve maximum variance over x and y and testing on a set that has been selected on a year that is not in the train set. I do however suspect that some techniques (tree learners) could benefit from  a prune set that has been separated on the same grounds as the test set.

Now most algorithms separate prune sets on initialisation themselves, but I want to experiment with a user defined set. In the current setup, rules that have been generated on local effects, would contribute less to performance in a test run, but the prune routine should be less equipped to predict that behavior.

Does anybody have experience with this? Do you know how to practically do that? Or do you know of a good theoretical resource on the subject?

Comment: as far as i understood your question, you would like to have a custom labeled test set, pre defined based on some features criteria for performance benchmark later. if that is the case then i could try and write down some way i would do this in `r`

Comment: Hey @davidski, not exactly: I **have** a custom test set. This proved _very_ necessary, so necessary in fact that I beleive pruning the classifier with a set (3rd set: training set, prune set, test set) that was selected along similar criteria would also improve performance. The tree learner i use in Weka however, doesn't offer that facility. The prune set is always generated automatically.